# How to install TesseractOCR in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

When I ssh my app,I try to get tesseract：

```
$wget http://leptonica.googlecode.com/files/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
```

It told me I cannot write this files(Permission denied)
so,Can I install tesseract in openshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change directories to your openshift data dir first using `cd ~/app-root/data` , then you can run your wget command